# how to preserve special character while using replace text in NIFI?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently trying to use replace text processor which has flow file incoming from a   update attribute processor .There I had used `${line:escapeJson()}` to  preserve the backslash `"\"` .Where as while using replacetext I see  backslash is being ignore .For ex: If attribute is `C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\` its becoming `C:\WINDOWS\\system32\cmd.exe`. I can try to manipulate this with expression language like `${line:replace("\\","\\\\"):escapeJson()}` .But I would like to know If there is a better way of doing same with out using replace  in expression language .

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I was naïve on this adding ${line:escapeJson()} in replace text will solve the problem

Comment: It's not clear what do you have at the beginning and what you want to achieve.